# Angular JS. What the order of actions in HTML when creating a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I have just a problem rightly ask a question).
I created angularJS app 'myApp'. And app get list of two groups. And app should to represent on browser two checkboxes: first - checked, second - empty.
But maybe I didn't count the order of action of building of angular's directives.
This is example

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="myApp">
      
      <div ng-controller="MainController">
       <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <mygroups info='group'></mygroups>   
       </div>
      </div>
    
      <script type="text/javascript">
          var groups = [
           {
            "id":"769",  "spam_status":"checked"},
           {
            "id":"1262", "spam_status":""}
          ];
          
       var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    
       app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
        $scope.groups  = groups; 
       });
    
       app.directive("mygroups", function(){
        return{
         scope:   {info: "="},
         template:  "<input type='checkbox' id='{{group.id}}'> {{info.id}}",
         //WORK FOR FIRST CHECKBOX IF TYPE: //BUT IT IS NO SENSE//
         // template: "<input type='checkbox' id='769'> {{info.id}}",
         controller:   function(){
          for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++){
           $('#' + groups[i].id).attr(groups[i].spam_status,'');
          }
         }
        };
       });
    
         </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

I get a right 'id' of element on front-end when I inspected code on browser. If I put on template number '769' instead {{info.id}}, the first checkbox will checked.
But I think that controller of directive acts before assignment 'id' of elements.
But I need realize this by that method. Because I try to explain on scratches the situation which I don't understand.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have just known about "ng-checked". And i should send on 'spam_status'='true' or 'false'.

Comment: And i dont already  need on jquery method. It is solve problem in my context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues :

### First point

Your template is :

```
<input type='checkbox' id='{{group.id}}'> {{info.id}}
```

It should be :

```
<input type='checkbox' id='{{info.id}}'> {{info.id}}
```

### Second point

You must call your dom modification in a $timeout function. On the first execution of your controller, your html does not exists yet.
$timeout will trigger the code at the next digest. So, your html will exists.

Of course, **do not modify your html in your controller** (even in a directive). The link function is the place to modify the html.

### Corrected snippet

Here is the snippet with the correction. There is a jquery error, I didn't watch what it is. Do not hesitate to edit to throw it away.

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-app="myApp">
      
      <div ng-controller="MainController">
       <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <mygroups info='group'></mygroups>   
       </div>
      </div>
    
      <script type="text/javascript">
          var groups = [
           {
            "id":"769",  "spam_status":"checked"},
           {
            "id":"1262", "spam_status":""}
          ];
          
       var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    
       app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
        $scope.groups  = groups; 
       });
    
       app.directive("mygroups", function(){
        return{
         scope:   {info: "="},
         template:  "<input type='checkbox' id='{{info.id}}'> {{info.id}}",
         //WORK FOR FIRST CHECKBOX IF TYPE: //BUT IT IS NO SENSE//
         // template: "<input type='checkbox' id='769'> {{info.id}}",
         controller:   function($timeout){
         $timeout(function() {
           for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++){
             $('#' + groups[i].id).attr(groups[i].spam_status,'');
           }
         });
          
         }
        };
       });
    
         </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ok. I will do your recommendation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to hook the checkbox up

```
template:   "<input type='checkbox' ng-model='info.spam_status' ng-true-value='\'checked\'' id='{{group.id}}'> {{info.id}}"
```